# My LoadCharacter() Script Isn't Working Properly

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a LoadCharacter() script, but when it runs it makes the player load several times before they actually load.

Here is the code:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.LoadCharacter.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
        player:LoadCharacter()
    end)
    player:LoadCharacter()
end)
```

BTW I disabled CharacterAutoLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your connection is inside the PlayerAdded event. It is causing the event to register callbacks every single time a player joins. So when any player fires the event, it is causing EVERYONE to reload their character.

So just move the connection outside it, and get the player object from the RemoteEvent. The first argument from `OnServerEvent` is always the player that called `FireServer` so you don't need to make any changes to your LocalScript.

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player:LoadCharacter()
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.LoadCharacter.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    player:LoadCharacter()
end)
```

Comment: This solution didn't work.